# Making a separated component disappear with useReducer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently learning the React Hooks feature so I created a small experiment where an invisible(unmounted) box would appear if the button is clicked; if the box is visible and you click on anywhere on the page except the box, the box would disappear. I'm struggling making the box disappear and I don't know what's causing the bug.

**Initial state and the reducer:**

```
const initialState = { visible: false };

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'show':
            return { visible: true };

        case 'hide':
            return { visible: false };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

**The Box component:**

```
function Box() {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const boxElement = useRef(null);
    const boxStyle = {
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px',
        background: 'blue'
    };

    function hideBox(e) {
        if(!boxElement.current.contains(e.target)) {
            dispatch({ type: 'hide' });
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('click', hideBox);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('click', hideBox);
        }
    });

    return <div style={boxStyle} ref={boxElement} />
}
```

**Main:**

```
function App() {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    function showBox() {
        dispatch({ type: 'show' });
    }

    return (
        <section>
            { state.visible && <Box /> }
            <button onClick={showBox}>Show box</button>
        </section>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two instances of useReducer whereas you only need to have one at the `App component` level and pass `dispatch as a prop to Box` otherwise you would only be updating the state that is used by the useReducer in Box and not the state in App component

```
function App() {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    function showBox() {
        dispatch({ type: 'show' });
    }

    return (
        <section>
            { state.visible && <Box dispatch={dispatch}/> }
            <button onClick={showBox}>Show box</button>
        </section>
    )
}
```

Box.js

```
function Box({dispatch}) {
    const boxElement = useRef(null);
    const boxStyle = {
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px',
        background: 'blue'
    };

    function hideBox(e) {
        if(!boxElement.current.contains(e.target)) {
            dispatch({ type: 'hide' });
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('click', hideBox);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('click', hideBox);
        }
    });

    return <div style={boxStyle} ref={boxElement} />
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n31k3koq2p)

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful tip. So, an ancestor component should always be the source of `dispatch()`?

Comment: @jstarnate yes, just like store global when using redux, same is the concept of reducer here, components that need to share the reducer state need to access the same reducer